# Removing decimal parts from a data grid view column

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell-formatting

I'm hoping to find a simple way to convert an entire column in my datagridview from a string data type to a decimal. Something simple like this maybe?

```
DataGridView1.Columns(4).ValueType = Integer;
```

While the data inserted into the DataGridView1 from a data table brought from database having money type ,but I don't want the decimal part
data now: 30000.0000
What I want: 30000

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function typeof() Like this:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(4).ValueType = typeof(System.Int32);
```

Comment: I tried it ,but the datagridview keeps refreshing and the application hangs !

Comment: Are you trying this after loading the data?

Comment: Yes, after the line (datagridview.DataSource = dt;)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format of your incoming data is always consistent, you can leverage Substring like so:

```
int myIntFromString = int.Parse(myString.Substring(0, myString.IndexOf('.')));
```

If you want the actual data in the DataGridView to be formatted in such a way, you'd have to implement that at the time the DataGridView is populated.